# Why does the distribution of BFV's sk use $R_2$, and what are the disadvantages of using $\chi$?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

> Instead of sampling $\mathbf{s},\mathbf{u} \gets \chi$, we will sample $\mathbf{s},\mathbf{u}$ from $R_2$, i.e. the norm $||\mathbf{s}||=||\mathbf{u}|| = 1$.
> $\cdots$.
> The security implications of this optimisation seem to be minor, at least when we make the assumption that the results for the LWE setting carry over to the RLWE setting.

In the original BFV scheme, including the optimized scheme, $\mathbf{s}$ is sampled from $R_2$. I know this will help slow down the noise growth. But I'm confused whether there is a proven lemma for security.

> Assume that the
> LWE analysis also holds for the RLWE setting.

Is this absolute?

Another question is whether the BFV scheme still works when $\mathbf{s}$ samples from $\chi$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "sort of".
The hardness assumption where $s\in\{0,1\}^n$ (or sometimes $\{-1,0,1\}$) is known as LWE with *binary secrets*.
Searching on that term will produce several papers, such as [this](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Edaniele/papers/BinLWE.pdf) and [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/265).
I won't reproduce the precise findings of these papers (which can be somewhat intricate), but will simply note that often one can assume binary secrets, but they show that one can often assume binary secrets, at the cost of inflating the dimension and size of the noise.

Note that I say "often", and not "always".
The more general of the two papers (the second) is for "Module LWE" where the module rank $d$ must be "large" (at least logarithmic in a certain parameter).
While Ring LWE is commonly used (and can be viewed as an instance of Module LWE), it is a Module LWE instance of constant (=1) module rank.
This is to say that while hardness results are known for LWE and MLWE, it is only for certain parameter ranges of MLWE, and I believe hardness of RLWE with binary secrets is an open problem.

Note that RLWE with Binary secrets, while not formally justified, is not the most aggressive assumption (whether this is good or bad is personal taste).
Practitioners often further assume

- small error ($\sigma = O(1)$ rather than $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$), and
- sparse (in terms of hamming weight) binary secrets.

As for the question

> whether the BFV scheme still works when s samples from $\chi$.

I don't know for BFV in particular, but often the answer is "it works, you just get an efficiency hit".
You would have to check the noise growth during bootstrapping in particular, and see if one can control it with the larger secret size.
This is fairly mechanical to do, and might be a good way to test your understanding of the scheme.